# a NONE in the output

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry, I would like users to input a letter but I dun understand why the display will show a None.

```
import random
hangmanList = {"fruit":["apple","banana","orange"]}
topicList = ["fruit"]
randomTopic = random.choice(topicList)
wordList = hangmanList[randomTopic]
questionList = random.choice(wordList)

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Hangman Game")
    print("---------------------------")
    print("Please choose 1 letter at a time")
    print("Topic is: ",randomTopic)
    guesses = input(print("Guesses: "))

main()
```

the output shows:

Welcome to the Hangman Game

---

Please choose 1 letter at a time

Topic is:  fruit

Guesses: 
None

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
guesses = input("Guesses: ")
```

`print` returns `None`.  `input` prints its argument as a prompt.

Comment: thanks alot! i have been searching for an answer but dun realli understand what the other comment were saying

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer is useful, please upvote them and accept the most useful one using the controls to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
guesses = input('Guesses: ')
```

Currently it is `None` because the `print()` function does not return a value, thus it's result is `None`. So

```
guesses = input(print('Guesses: ')) 
# is
guesses = input(None)
```